# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkflow'

Tags: python, deep-learning

I've installed Darkflow-master module by running

```
 python setup.py build_ext --inplace.
```

A build folder is created. But when I try to compile my file it shows this error

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkflow' "

```
import cv2
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import numpy as np
import time

option = {
   'model': 'cfg/yolo.cfg',
   'load': 'bin/yolo.weights',
   'threshold': 0.15,
   'gpu': 1.0
}

tfnet = TFNet(option)
```

Comment: Just build the Cython extensions in place. "NOTE: If installing this way you will have to use ./flow in the cloned darkflow directory instead of flow as darkflow is not installed globally."

python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace

It says in the documentation that this way doesn't install darkflow globally.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you for your advice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure to:

- Clone the [repo](https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow).
- open cmd and cd into the repo folder `cd darkflow-master`
- type in cmd: `pip install .`
  this will install darkflow globally around your computer or,
  if you're using anaconda it will install it globally within that
  specific environment you're running the command from

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

"NOTE: If installing this way you will have to use ./flow in the cloned darkflow directory instead of flow as darkflow is not installed globally."

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```